# Incomplete Table of Contents (TOC) while using the memoir class and the booklet package

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, booklet

I'm trying to generate a small TOC of a booklet with a few chapters and some sections, but the only thing that is generated is its title (i.e. Contents).  I haven't found the root cause of the problem yet, does anyone can help?

Here's an excerpt of the document code:

```
    \documentclass[legalpaper,11pt]{memoir}

    \setlrmarginsandblock{.5in}{.25in}{*}
    \setulmarginsandblock{2in}{1.5in}{*}

    \setlength{\columnsep}{.25in}
    \setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
    \setlength{\textheight}{10.5in}
    \setlength{\textwidth}{8in}
    \setlength{\marginparwidth}{.05in}
    \setlength{\marginparsep}{.05in}
    \setlength{\spinemargin}{.05in}
    \checkandfixthelayout
    \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{.05in}

    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{color}
    %\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
    \usepackage[print,largetypeblock]{booklet} \nofiles
    \pagespersignature{20}
    \ifpdf
    \setpdftargetpages
    \else
    \setdvipstargetpages
    \fi
    \ifprintoption % tweak dvi output only for final printing
    \special{!TeXDict begin /landplus90{true}store end}
    \special{!TeXDict begin <</Tumble true>> setpagedevice end}
    \fi
    \title{Title}
    \date{\today}
    \author{}
    \makeindex
    \begin{document}
        \pagestyle{empty}
        \begin{center}
            % \includegraphics[scale=.35]{../images/rosarium.jpg}
            % {\LARGE \\lat\'in - espa\~nol}
        \end{center}

        \newpage

        \begin{center}
            \vspace*{\fill}

            \textbf{
                \LARGE
                Title
            }
            \textbf{
                \Large
                \\Title
            }

            \vspace*{2in}
            \vfill

            \small
            \textbf{
                Authors
            }

            \vspace*{.25in}
            % \includegraphics[width=133pt,scale=.3]{../images/uvpr.jpg}

            \vspace*{1in}
            \vfill
            \textbf{
                City, State, Country\\
                \today
            }
            \vfill
            \newpage
        \end{center}

        \pagestyle{plain}
        \pagenumbering{roman}
        \maketitle
        \tableofcontents
        \cleardoublepage

        \pagestyle{headings}
        \pagenumbering{arabic}
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        % Page 1
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \chapter{Modo de rezar}
        \clearpage

        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        % Page 2
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        % \includegraphics[scale=.9]{../images/rosarium.pdf}

        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        % Page 3
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \chapter{Oraciones}
        \clearpage

        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        % Page 4 - Column 1
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \begin{multicols}{2}

        \end{multicols}
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        % Page 18
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \end{document}
```

Comment: You have an `\nofiles` statement which indicates that no `.aux` etc. file is written at all, as such, no `.toc` etc. can be generated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Warning: The preamble is a little bit strange and I don't address issues other than the main problem: `\nofiles`

If `\nofiles` is used, no `.aux` file is generated from the beginning (or if `\nofiles` is added between two runs, the `.aux` file won't be updated.

As such either `.toc` is not generated at all or it is not updated.

Running with `\nofiles` right from the start, it will never generate `.aux`, `.toc` etc.

```
 \documentclass[legalpaper,11pt]{memoir}

    \setlrmarginsandblock{.5in}{.25in}{*}
    \setulmarginsandblock{2in}{1.5in}{*}

    \setlength{\columnsep}{.25in}
    \setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
    \setlength{\textheight}{10.5in}
    \setlength{\textwidth}{8in}
    \setlength{\marginparwidth}{.05in}
    \setlength{\marginparsep}{.05in}
    \setlength{\spinemargin}{.05in}
    \checkandfixthelayout
    \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{.05in}

    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{color}
    %\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
    \usepackage[print,largetypeblock]{booklet} 
    % \nofiles
    \pagespersignature{20}
    \ifpdf
    \setpdftargetpages
    \else
    \setdvipstargetpages
    \fi
    \ifprintoption % tweak dvi output only for final printing
    \special{!TeXDict begin /landplus90{true}store end}
    \special{!TeXDict begin <</Tumble true>> setpagedevice end}
    \fi
    \title{Title}
    \date{\today}
    \author{}
    \makeindex
    \begin{document}
        \pagestyle{empty}
        \begin{center}
            % \includegraphics[scale=.35]{../images/rosarium.jpg}
            % {\LARGE \\lat\'in - espa\~nol}
        \end{center}

        \newpage

        \begin{center}
            \vspace*{\fill}

            \textbf{
                \LARGE
                Title
            }
            \textbf{
                \Large
                \\Title
            }

            \vspace*{2in}
            \vfill

            \small
            \textbf{
                Authors
            }

            \vspace*{.25in}
            % \includegraphics[width=133pt,scale=.3]{../images/uvpr.jpg}

            \vspace*{1in}
            \vfill
            \textbf{
                City, State, Country\\
                \today
            }
            \vfill
            \newpage
        \end{center}

        \pagestyle{plain}
        \pagenumbering{roman}
        \maketitle
        \tableofcontents
        \cleardoublepage

        \pagestyle{headings}
        \pagenumbering{arabic}
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        % Page 1
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \chapter{Modo de rezar}
        \clearpage

        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        % Page 2
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        % \includegraphics[scale=.9]{../images/rosarium.pdf}

        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        % Page 3
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \chapter{Oraciones}
        \clearpage

        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        % Page 4 - Column 1
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \begin{multicols}{2}

        \end{multicols}
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        % Page 18
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Done, I have another problem with the TOC page numbers.  I have five chapters located in different sheets and pages; however, all of the page numbers appear as if the chapters were in the same page.  The whole document has more than 18 pages, but all the chapter entries display i (roman number one).

Comment: @ScutulatIum: That's another question. Please consider to accept this answer first, then ask another question